# Issues creating PodFile to wrap OpenCV 4.5.0 - No framework after install

Tags: opencv, cocoapods

I've created a new pod file for OpenCV 4.5.0, but I'm having a difficult time making it work. I sought out the latest pod file (which was version 4.1.0), updated it's license, and source mappings for 4.5.0, created a repository and added it to my own pod file to test.

When I run pod install/update, it says it's downloading the pod and updating the version to 4.5.0, but the framework doesn't end up in the project (so it doesn't compile).

The pod file tutorial on the website seems more geared towards how to make a pod file for your own project, but now how to wrap others (OpenCV doesn't provide an official pod spec).

My repo is here:
https://github.com/StainlessStlRat/OpenCVPodSpec/blob/main/OpenCV.podspec.json

My pod include is here:

```
pod 'OpenCV', :git => 'https://github.com/StainlessStlRat/OpenCVPodSpec.git'
```

One final question, once I do get *it* working, how do I push this pod to spec so everyone can have it?